# Highcharts gantt Y axis label left align not padded

Tags: highcharts, label, highcharts-gantt

We use the Gantt chart with a Y axis containing a treegrid.
We want to left align the labels in the treegrid but the labels are sticked to the border of the cells. We would like to let a left padding but the options (x, padding...)

```
labels:{
        align: 'left',
        x: 15,
        padding: 15
     },
```

seem to not have any effect.

The following sample show the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/809a6b5z
What is the correct syntax to let a space in front of each label ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add padding using CSS styles. Just add `useHTML: true` to `yAxis.labels` and apply `div` with styles to all grid columns you want via `columns.labels.format` property:

```js
yAxis: {
  ...
  labels: {
    useHTML: true
  },
  grid: {
    ...
    columns: [{
      title: {
        text: 'Project'
      },
      labels: {
        format: '<div style="padding: 0 15px;">{point.name}</div>'
      }
    }, {
      title: {
        text: 'Assignee'
      },
      labels: {
        format: '<div style="padding: 0 15px;">{point.assignee}</div>'
      }
    },
    ...
   ]
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9snhxfru/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.labels.useHTML